# Broken links inside PHP emailer with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that sends emails using a PHP document.
The email body includes two links to images that are populated with a JS variables.

Most of the emails arrive good and the links work, but in some of them, the links (both or one of them) will come out broken, looking like this:

```
https://blabla.com/register/uploads/Frankfurt2018-22-03-2018-16-07-52.!
```

Or like this:

```
https://blabla.com/register/uploads/KoelnerListe2%21
```

Or like this:

```
https://blabla.com/register/upload!
```

It's weird cause sometimes is both links, sometimes is only one, and most of the times are correct.

The link variable comes from the Angular app and looks like this:

```
$scope.sendapplication = function(){

  $scope.photoor = "https://blabla.com/register/uploads/"+$scope.photoor;
  $scope.photosmall = "https://blabla.com/register/uploads/"+$scope.photo;

  $scope.exhibitor = {
    'img':$scope.photosmall,
    'imgoriginal':$scope.photoor,
  };

  var $promise=$http.post('emailtest.php',$scope.exhibitor); 

  $promise.then(function (data) {
    ...
  });

};
```

And in the php file I do this:

```
$contentType = explode(';', $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']); // Check all available Content-Type
$rawBody = file_get_contents("php://input"); // Read body

$data = array(); // Initialize default data array

if(in_array('application/json', $contentType)) { 
  $data = json_decode($rawBody); // Then decode it
  $photo = $data->img;
  $photooriginal = $data->imgoriginal;
} else {
  parse_str($data, $data); // If not JSON, just do same as PHP default method
}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode(array( // Return data
  'data' => $data
));

$sabine = 'blabla@gmail.com';

$headerss = "From: ".$galleryname."<".$email.">\r\nReturn-path: ".$email."";
$headerss .= "Reply-To: ".$galleryname."<".$email.">";
$headerss .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headerss .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$recipient = $sabine;

$subjects = "Registration for ".$fairumlaut." - ".$galleryname.""; 
$bodys .= "<p><strong>Original photo</strong>: <a href=".$photooriginal.">Link</a></p>";
$bodys .= "<p><strong>Web resized photo</strong>: <a href=".$photo.">Link</a></p>";
$bodys .= "<p></p>";

mail($recipient, $subjects, $bodys, $headerss);
```

What could cause such weird behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the link in urlencode function.  This will solve your issue.

update: or if I read your code I would have seen that the links are coming from JS.  Try encodeURI().. ;)